# Akka actors returning different types of output

Tags: scala, generics, akka

I have a project that is using Akka Actors in scala, and I'm running into some issues regarding the actors that do processing and send the results back to the sender.

To better explain, here is the workflow that my project has

- Commander send msg to Poller

  - Poller sends SuccessMessage(self, List[String]) to Commander
- Commander sends List[String] to Processor

  - Processor sends SuccessMessage(self, File) to Commander
- Commander sends File to Uploader

  - Uploader sends SuccessMessage(self, Boolean) to Commander
- and so on.

Essentially, I have two questions:

Right now, I wrap everything that is returned from an actor back to the Commander (supervisor) in a SuccessMessage. Is this the best way of doing it, or is there another way to handle many different types of return?

The SuccessMessage will also have a "payload". I am debating between using generics for the payload type, or just making it an Option[Any] and then doing a lot of casting on the commander side, before sending it to any actor (poller, processor, etc.). I know that in Java akka actors just cast Object; would I have to do the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "right" way, but I this is how I would do it:

Make messages unique to each actor type pair. Wrap the actual data in these messages: `Poll(something)`, `Polled(result)`, `Process(something)`, `Processed(result)`, `Upload(something)` and `Uploaded(result)`.

Then either make `PollFailed(details)`, `ProcessingFailed(details)` and `UploadFailed(details)` messages or put `Option` in the normal result messages. I like using `Option`.

I'd define these messages in the `Poller`'s, `Processer`'s and `Uploader`'s companion objects.

The commander's receive method is then quite pretty:

```
def receive = {
  case Polled(Some(result)) => // handle
  case Polled(None) => // handle
  case Processed(Some(result)) => // handle
  case Processed(None) => // handle
  case Uploaded(Some(result)) => // handle
  case Uploaded(None) => // handle
}
```

Stay away from generics. Thanks to type erasure you cannot match generics in the receive method.

Comment: Thanks Quizzie. The problem is, in this project, there are several commanders (for doing different work) and several actors for each commander, and adding on the success/failure messages, there would be a lot of extra objects added. Instead, I think the better option might just be casting...

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen your code, but I would suggest doing two things:

1. Create different types of messages for success. E.g.

   - `MessagesPolled(List[String])`,
   - `MessagesProcessed(File)`
   - `MessagesUploaded` and `MessagesNotUploaded(Error)`

   This way your logic will be divided in proper and logic connected to each message will be held in different place (and later on can be changed without affecting other logics).
2. Create hierarchy of actors so that each of them is responsible for one thing (including the top actor), e.g.:

   - `Commander` has references to three actors (which have their own worker `hierarchies`):

     - `Poller` which only routes messages to dynamically created `PollerWorker`s
     - `Processor` which only routes messages to dynamically created `ProcessorWorker`s
     - `Uploader` which only routes messages to dynamically created `UploaderWorker`s
   - `Commander` receives a trigger message and sends first message to `Poller` with a `ActorRef` to the `nextStepActor` which, in the case of first message, will be `ProcessorWorker`

   This way you will be able to encapsulate logic in different actors, scale easily and not overwhelm the `Commander` actor.